# Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed. Failed to initialize plugins. Cannot start mysql in linux server

Tags: mysql, linux, innodb

We have been trying so many solutions to the problem that we can not start mysql. But no solution is working. When we check mysql error log, we can see below errors:

```
[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
[ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
[ERROR] Aborting
    
[Note] Binlog end
[Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
[Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
[Note] Shutting down plugin 'keyring_file'
[Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

When we try to login by sql command from terminal, it gives us ,"Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)".
[image: mysqld.cnf file]

[image: When we try to restart mysql, following errors occured in the image]

Comment: @Markus Fantastic news! Thanks for sharing it! And... why you did so?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. Our problem is solved. It was storage issue. No space was freed to write log files in server. Then we freed some space and it started to work again.